# How to make a click function stop working after a div box is colored?

Tags: javascript

I have a box on click function, when you click on the box it gets either red or blue.
Is there any way to make the click function stop working after the box is colored.
If the box is colored the click function should stop working.
Thx!

code;

```
if (box1.style.backgroundColor == "red" || box1.style.backgroundColor == "blue") {
            $("#box1").click(function (){
                // return nothing 
            });
        }
```

color change code:

```
$("#box1").click(function () {
        clickCounter++;
        if (clickCounter % 2 == 0) {
            box1.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        } else {
            box1.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
        }
```

Comment: How does color gets changed ?

Comment: Either remove the click handler from the box, or remeber inside the handler that you clicked before.

Comment: Give it a try: https://jsfiddle.net/zt4h5qm9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your if statement inside of the click event

```
$("#box1").click(function (){
   if (box1.style.backgroundColor == "red" || box1.style.backgroundColor == "blue") {
      return false;
   }

    // your code 
    clickCounter++;
    if (clickCounter % 2 == 0) {
        box1.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    } else {
        box1.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    }
});
```

Comment: You're welcome. You could also unbind the click event, like the answer below.

Comment: I think this is a workaround... the click event still working after the box is coloured, and JS will process each click. The effective way is unbinding the event

Comment: 'Works fine' is not the same that 'Works efficiently'. As developer you should think in both. I know this solve the problem, but many people gave you better solutions @G.D

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$.off()` to remove any event. Following is a code depicting same.

> [$.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

```js
$(".oneClick").on("click", function(){
  var color = (Math.random()*10).toFixed(0)%2 == 0?"red":"blue"
  $(this).css({"background" : color});
  $(this).off("click");
})
```

```css
.oneClick{
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  border:2px solid gray;
  background:orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="oneClick"></div>
```

Comment: It's worth noting that if you use `.off()` with no arguments it clears all events from the element which would also suffice in this case! (Yes, I know that it is better to define which event you want to remove, it's more of a point of interest than anything)

Comment: Thats true, but using it with argument makes it more readable and also prevents from removing any other event.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way using [jQuery unbind function](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) :

```
$("#box1").click(function () {
    clickCounter++;
    if (clickCounter % 2 == 0) {
        box1.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        $( "#box1").unbind( "click" );
    } else {
        box1.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
        $( "#box1").unbind( "click" );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As you defined an eventListener with `$.click()` method you can remove it as follow:

```
$('.clickbox').on('click', function() {
  var $currentBox = $(this); // get the box you just clicked (this is the method you need)

  $currentBox.css({
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  })  

  $currentBox.off('click'); // remove the click event listener
})
```

Exemple:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKyOwO

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to add and remove a listener, I think it is cleaner something [like this](https://jsbin.com/nudiwe/edit?html,css,js,output)